# How did Homura get a bow as a weapon?

Tags: madoka-magica

In the last episode of *Puella Magi Madoka Magica* TV anime, Homura seems to have Madoka's bow. In earlier episodes, she only use guns and bombs, when and how did she get this weapon?[image: Break?! Shoot!!]

Comment: Well, this IS an alternative universe now. Maybe she adopted Madokas weapon subconsciously? If you've seen the 3rd movie, you'll realize pretty much anything goes for this series..

Comment: Homura's power was originally time manipulation, she learned how to make bombs from the internet and stole guns from the military and used these in conjunction with her powers (as we see in her fight with Walpurgisnacht), she could have very well gotten her hand on a bow in homage to Madoka

Answer (score 12):

> She got her weapon from Madoka.

This is a question for [Gen Urobuchi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gen_Urobuchi) (Puella Magi Madoka Magica writer) at a [Nitro+ Q&A Panel](http://wiki.puella-magi.net/Nitro+_Q&A_Panels_at_Animagic_2013)

Q: Did Homura get her weapon from Madoka?

> A: The weapon Homura got filled the hole that Madoka left when she couldn't use the bow anymore. [Note: I'm not sure if I got this right, maybe someone who still remembers the details of Madoka's ending properly could fill me in with the details of this]

Comment: but one thing I don't understand is, why he said that he wasn't sure? isn't he himself who wrote Puella Magi Madoka Magica?

Comment: I suppose `I' in the bracket signifies the person who recorded the QA panel, not Gen Urobuchi himself.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because in the new universe, Homura didn't have to use her wish for the sake of saving Madoka. She had no need for time manipulation, so instead of that device, she now has a bow. In the Q&A answer section (as cited in the other answer), it's said the bow was to fill in the hole, being that there is no cause that would have Homura gain the Time Manipulation ability in the new universe.

Answer (score 1):

This is resolved by *Wraith Arc*: She arrived in the new universe with her old powers intact, however due to the same miracle that allowed her to retain memories of the old universe (her mutual love for Madoka), she was able to obtain a second wish:

> "Those are my feelings towards Madoka! That's why, once more, lend me power! Not as the shield that protects Madoka but as the power that smites anyone who threatens her!"

As such, she was given an appropriate weapon, the bow of memory manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

By searching about this it makes me think, She probably didn't get this from Madoka or whoever it is, She got the bow through her wish as she said "Those are my feelings towards Madoka! That's why, once more, lend me power! Not as the shield that protects Madoka but as the power that smites anyone who threatens her!" since her shield was obtained by wraith.